# Hash key access error

Tags: javascript, object, key

I'm having this weird error while accessing the key `evenimente` of my object. Any ideas why?

It clearly is available but I cannot access it via `.(dot)`

[image]

EDIT: Sorry, here is the code

```
var isPresent = function(entry) {
            var evenimente = entry.evenimente;
            var elem = $("#" + entry.nume + "-" + entry.prenume);

            for(var i = 0; i < evenimente.length; i++) {
                var eveniment = evenimente[i];
                if(eveniment.eveniment_id == eventId && eveniment.user_id == entry.id) {
                    elem.prop('checked', true);
                }
            }

            elem.prop('checked', false);
        }
```

I get `entry` via ajax from the server

Comment: Do you mind adding your _secret_ code

Comment: From the image, the object is first element in array, so use `arr[0].evenimente`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your `entry` is an array (see the `[` and `]` in your console).

So, you should be able to access the `evenimente` field this way:

```
var ev = entry[0].evenimente
```

The updated code would look like this:

```
var isPresent = function (entry) {
    var evenimente = entry[0].evenimente;
    var elem = $("#" + entry[0].nume + "-" + entry[0].prenume);

    for (var i = 0; i < evenimente.length; i++) {
        var eveniment = evenimente[i];
        if (eveniment.eveniment_id == eventId && eveniment.user_id == entry[0].id) {
            elem.prop('checked', true);
        }
    }

    elem.prop('checked', false);
}
```

Also, for convenience, you could just override the `entry` value like below:

```
var isPresent = function (entry) {
    entry = entry[0];
    if (!entry) { 
       throw new Error("No available entry.");
    }
    var evenimente = entry.evenimente;
    var elem = $("#" + entry.nume + "-" + entry.prenume);

    for (var i = 0; i < evenimente.length; i++) {
        var eveniment = evenimente[i];
        if (eveniment.eveniment_id == eventId && eveniment.user_id == entry.id) {
            elem.prop('checked', true);
        }
    }

    elem.prop('checked', false);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, sometimes too much debugging makes you blind :)).. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! You just need to get used to it: debugging all day, all night. `:-)`

Comment: While at school too :))